# SimpleForm remove wrapper divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm in my Ruby on Rails app. To make my input look  good with my current css I need to disable wrapper every time for the input:

```
f.input :email, wrapper: false, input_html: { class: 'input' }
```

How can I remove this wrapper globally?

Comment: You can use input_field instead of input to avoid wrapper (not globally, anyway).

Comment: Did you read options in './config/initializers/simple_form.rb' file?

Answer (score 3):

If by "globally" you mean all forms in application, then I don't think it can be done through standard configuration in config/initializers/simple_form.rb. However, you can easily disable wrappers in a form by setting defaults for all inputs in it:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, defaults: { wrapper: false } do |f| %>
```

Please remember that wrappers in simple_form are highly configurable and controlling classes for them is possible with options available in initializer.